# Is possible generate optimal parent sets in R using package bnlearn?

Tags: r, bayesian, bnlearn

We could calculate the score of the bayesian network using the function "score", but I need calculate the score of all possible parents set from a node. 
I mean if I have n variables(X1,X2, X3, ..., Xn), I want calculate the score for X1 and all possible parents set.